# no method error for 'name" when I try to paginate news items with kaminari

Tags: rubygems, kaminari

I have been struggling to correct an issue with "undefined method `name'" when I have installed the kaminari gem.

Error message:
undefined method`name' for nil:NilClass

```
Extracted source (around line #3):

<article class="body">
  <header>
    <h1><%= @news_item.name %></h1>
 </header>
 <%= @news_item.body %>
</article>
```

I have this in my routes file:

```
resources :news, :only => [:index, :show]

namespace :admin do
  resources :news_items
end
```

The partial for news item:

```
   %article.body
    = @news_item.name
    = @news_item.body
```

The news controller:

```
class NewsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @news_items = NewsItem.order("id").page(params[:page]).per(5) 

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html #do nothing.
      format.json { render :json => @news_items.to_json }
      format.xml { render :xml => @news_items.to_xml }
    end
  end
  def show
    @news_item = NewsItem.find params[:id]
  end

end
```

And for news#index:

```
= paginate @news_items
= render :partial => "/shared/news_item", :collection => @news_items
```

Can anyone please identify why I can not get past this issue of no method error?

Thanks

David